# Is there a Stack Overflow-like site for programs like Fireworks or Photoshop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I just want to know if there is a forum like Stack Overflow for graphic designers.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no SE site for what you want. The [Graphic Design proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) is more than halfway to beta status, though.

Depending on *exactly* what you want, it *might* be appropriate for you to ask at the [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/). Their rule is that "Photoshop questions" are okay [as long as the thing you're Photoshopping is an actual photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-this-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-questions-about-how-to-accomplish-an-effect) from a camera, not something created from scratch on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Doctype](http://doctype.com/) is for web designers.  There are lots of questions involving Photoshop and Fireworks usage for web design.

If you're having a problem with the Photoshop or Fireworks applications, there's [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).  Adobe also has a pretty good community / forum for their apps.

Answer (score -1):

Scroll to the bottom of this window. You'll see links to all the available SO related sites.

Comment: -1 because betas are not listed in the footer

Answer (score -1):

If the site doesn't exist, you can look to see if anyone has proposed it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), or propose it yourself.